# elasticsearch on linux for windows Logs

Tags: elasticsearch

can i  install elasticsearch on linux in order to run on it queries, for logs that are created on Windows servers?

My application runs on windows server, but in order to save money i want to run elasticsearch on linux, it should receive the log files from windows servers.
Kibana should run lo on linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run both on any system, both communicate via HTTP and are system agnostic.